# How to get any information from 1102,1104,1105,1106 ports?

Tags: network, openssl, nmap, ports

I have port output from nmap scan below.

> 1102/tcp  open     ssl/adobeserver-1?
>
> 1104/tcp  open     ssl/xrl?
>
> 1105/tcp  open     ssl/ftranhc?
>
> 1106/tcp  open     ssl/isoipsigport-1?

I tried `telnet` and `openssl s_client -host *host* -port *port*` and connected to these ports. But I don't get any answer.

How to communicate with them? The don't response at all.

Comment: What operating system is the target machine running?

Comment: @korockinout13, Linux

Comment: Do you have shell access on the target machine?

Comment: @korockinout13, No(

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the service listening to these ports. Often when ports are in sequence, like your output, there is just one process running multiple instances each bound to its own port.

Without any info about the server, it is hard to tell what protocol is used to communicate over these ports. For all we know it's a custom network protocol, allowing only certain types of data or addresses.

You *could* feed a stream of `/dev/urandom` endlessly to see if something comes back. I can ensure you, the successrate is low.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that any process should give something as response to any request. Like "qwe-qwe"->"Hi, my name is *service* and I do not understand you. Please, go home."

Comment: @user3360601: this depends entirely on the application protocol spoken. For example HTTP or SSL will wait for the client to start. If the client send nonconforming data SSL will probably just close the connection while others will just wait until they get the expected data. SMTP, POP, IMAP, FTP start with a message send by the server to the client.